# How to redirect System.out using different thread in JavaFX with FXML

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have multiple tabs and one of them is my console output. I am trying to redirect `System.out`/`err` to `TextArea loggerPane` in that console output Tab using JavaFX. My question is how can I do that in a different thread because while it's outputting I can't navigate to the console tab.

Main App:

```
public initRootLayout(){
    FXMLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(RootLayout.fxml))
    rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
    scene = new Scene (rootLayout);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    rootLayoutController = loader.getController();
    rootLayoutController.setMainApp(this);
    primaryStage.show();
   }
```

I included the ConsoleController in RootController where I have all the tabs

```
 @FXML private ConsoleController consoleController
```

RootLayoutFXML: I included the consoleFXML that uses its own controller

```
<Tab text="Console">
 <content>
    fx:include fx:id="myConsolePane" source="console.fxml"
 </content>
</Tab>
```

ConsoleController

```
 public class ConsoleController implements Initializable {
            @FXML 
            private TextArea loggerPane;
            public void appendText(String valueOf){
                Platform.runLater(()-> loggerPane.appendText(valueOf))
            }

            @Override
            public void initialize (URL ur, ResourceBundle rb){
            OutputStream out = new OutputStream(){
                @Override
                public void write(int b) throws IOException{
                    appendText(String.valueOf((char)b));
                }
            };
            System.setOut(out, true);
            System.setErr(out, true);
        }
```

Background Thread:

```
It's calling background class that interacts with a Rest API to
preform a function, sometime it outputs a long string as part of 
the validation which I want to capture in the console tab.
```

Comment: Can you show what your background thread is doing and how you are starting it, etc? This looks fundamentally correct, but it has the potential to create a huge number of `Runnable`s to execute on the FX Application Thread (one per character!!!). If that's the problem, and you can't move the `Platform.runLater(...)` to a point in the code where it is dealing with data in greater bulk, you may need to implement some kind of buffer that you periodically empty to the text area.

Comment: Hello James, sorry for my delayed response. I updated the question with more detail, I hope this can help you to point me into the right direction.